# How to remove the 'Title Section' from <RichTextEditor> in 'react-native-zss-rich-text-editor' package?

Tags: react-native, rich-text-editor, velo

I am using [react-native-zss-rich-text-editor](https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor) for rich text editor and it displays the editor as shown in the below image,[image]

As shown in the image there are two sections title and body.I would like to have only body section in editor.

Hence, Is it possible to remove the title section?

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible to have one section, just remove the title section by passing the attribute hiddenTitle and set it to true.

```
  <RichTextEditor
       ...
       hiddenTitle= {true}
       ...
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.